# How to disable file sharing in Android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-fileprovider

I am using `FileProvider` and `Intents` to share content from our application to other applications. Using these components can also upload data from other applications to our application. For security reasons, we want to only disable sharing from our application to other applications. Is there a global solution to have this restriction put in place?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> FileProvider enables to share content from our application to other applications.

Only by having additional code in your app. `FileProvider`, *on its own*, does not do what you describe.

> It also provides capabilities to upload data from other applications to our application.

Again, this only happens if you have have additional code in your app. `FileProvider`, *on its own*, does not do this.

> Is there a global solution to have this restriction put in place?

Do not write the code that implements sharing from your application to other applications.

Comment: > Only by having additional code in your app. FileProvider, on its own, does not do what you describe 
Agreed. We share a file with another app using a content URI which can be retrieved from `FileProvider.getUriForFile()`. We can send this content URI to another app using an Intent. 
So there is definitely additional code to be written in both cases I mentioned. 

I can remove all the code for sharing, but looking to see if there’s a way to disable this functionality throughout the application.

Comment: @androidstruggler: "I can remove all the code for sharing" -- and that is what you will need to do. "looking to see if there’s a way to disable this functionality throughout the application" -- delete the code.

Comment: Is that the only option? I am trying to build out a more platform agnostic solution. I know that there are many companies out their who does this (like Microsoft, MobileIron etc). Do you know how this is done?

Comment: @androidstruggler: "Is that the only option?" -- you are welcome to do something else to prevent your code from running. "Do you know how do they do that?" -- as far as I can tell, what Intune does is what you said you do not want to do: Intune shares (sometimes); you want to disable this entirely. If you want to do what Intune does and share only in certain situations, you can do that, but *you* will have to write code that wraps *your* existing sharing code, to only share when conditions are appropriate.

Comment: @androidstruggler: "I know that there are many companies out their who does this (like Microsoft, MobileIron etc)" -- I do not know what "this" is. You might consider writing a new question, where you explain in greater detail exactly what functionality you are seeking. Your question is focused on `FileProvider` and blocking sharing entirely. `FileProvider` is not a prerequisite for sharing.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC your app must "opt in" to sharing its own files on a case-by-case basis. Other applications request files from your application, which must then grant them (temporary) permission and pass them the access URI. Other applications don't get automatic access to your files without asking. If you don't implement the sharing functionality, there is no way for a sharing request to be granted.

If you do want limited sharing you can also set up a policy XML file to restrict which directories owned by your application are shareable.

https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing